# Отправка после ввода символа

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть такой код:

```
{% extends "convector/layouts.html" %}
{% block extra_head %}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form.form_class").change(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            var form_data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                method: $(this).attr('method'),
                data: form_data,
                success: function (data) { $('.result_div').html(data.result); }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock extra_head %}
{% block main_section %}

<form action="/result/" method="get" class="form_class">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="InputConvert">Enter numbers</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="InputConvert" rows="10" required name="InputConvert"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <label for="OutputConvert">Convert</label>
            <textarea readonly id="StaticResult" rows="10" class="form-control result_div"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


{% endblock main_section %}
```

Нужно, чтобы на сервер отправлялось когда всё еще активно поле ввода. Сейчас отправка на сервер происходит после того, как нажать на пустое место, то есть сделать не активным поле ввода.

Кто сможет подсказать?

Comment: Для отслеживания ввода, используйте keypress() или keyup().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот стати по этой теме:

[keyup()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F_keyup) - Устанавливает обработчик возвращения клавиши клавиатуры в не нажатое состояние.

[keydown()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F_keydown) -Устанавливает обработчик перехода клавиши клавиатуры в нажатое состояние

[keypress()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F_keypress) -Устанавливает обработчик ввода символа с клавиатуры.

Используйте эти события вместо события change();

Comment: Отлично, благодарю

Comment: Именно то что искал

Comment: @Tigo Vir обращайтесь, всегда рад помочь)

Comment: Хорошо, ещё буду